# trying to do a spreadsheet for work tomorrow

Tags: worksheet-function

i have 3000 graduation tickets that need to be entered into excel by number 001-004, 005-008, 009-012, 013-016- etc. What formula do i use to complete this task. I tried dragging the first 5 rows but it did not calculate properly.

Comment: Please note that [SU] is not a script writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (including any scripts you are using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

In  **A1** enter:

```
=TEXT(4*(ROW()-1)+1,"000") & "-" & TEXT(4*(ROW()-1)+4,"000")
```

and copy down:

[image]